# Atmel ICE C initial connection problems

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmel, atmelstudio

I have ATMEL ICE C initial connection problems - it cannot read device signature, because of the target board voltage isn't between range of 1.8 to 5.5V. It has measured by the Atmel Studio as 1.3V (when target board is powered by the USB connector) or 0.3V (when USB disconnected from target).

- It'a a brand new device, and i never used it before, may be i did something wrong?
- I had used before AVR ISP handmade by myself, and had used previously programmed target board for this experiment, to avoid possibility, that board is dead. The target is works and blinking heart beat.

What i has done -

- 1.Connect the target board to the ICE programmer.
- 2.power target board by USB.
- 3.power programmer by  USB from PC USB port.
- 4.open "device programming" tab in AS 7.
- 5.Make all settings for my chip atmega328p
- 6.press "apply" then 'read'
- 7.get err msg that voltage is too low.
- (while i had measured it directly, by the digital voltmeter on pins +5V and GND on target
  board, it's about 4.5V, same as in ISP connector - measured on 2 and
  6 pins.)
- =======================================================
- @markus-nm where did you take your measurements?
- i had measured on pin 2 and 6 of ISP connector and between pin +5V and GND on Arduino Nano board.

What reference was used?

- i had used GND pin on target board for the reference.

Did you use the same USB Host for ISP and power?

- no, power to target board was from the wall socket USB charger, AND  power to Atmel ICE is from personal computer.

If not, did you connect the grounds?

- no, but i guess that grounds are already connected on the target board.

Some links to your chip, your board and ISP would be helpful.

- ATMEL-ICE-C  https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/ATATMEL-ICE
- ARDUINO NANO PRO https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano

If it's a custom PCB, provide some schematics. Show a wiring diagram of what you did.

- no, i had used the standard Nano board (may be not original, but clone, but it is definitely working now, because it can be programmed by the AVRDUDE program and work.)

Comment: You should clarify more, i.e. where did you take your measurements? What reference was used? Did you use the same USB Host for ISP and power? If not, did you connect the grounds? Some links to your chip, your board and ISP would be helpful. If it's a custom PCB, provide some schematics. Show a wiring diagram of what you did.

Comment: i.e. where did you take your measurements?
- i had measured on pin 2 and 6 of ISP connector and between pin +5V and GND on Arduino Nano board.
 What reference was used?

 Did you use the same USB Host for ISP and power?
- no, power to target board was from the wall socket USB charger, 

 If not, did you connect the grounds? Some links to your chip, your board and ISP would be helpful. If it's a custom PCB, provide some schematics. Show a wiring diagram of what you did.

Comment: @markus-nm, i had edited my base post and add some required info to this.

Answer (score 0):

The Atmel-ICE, by design, has a lot of different ways to hook up the programming connector.  Often when I see problems like this it's because the wrong connector is used.  Keep in mind the programmer itself has both an AVR and a SAM port.  For the Arduino Nano Pro, make sure it's plugged into the AVR port.  After that, ensure you're using the correct programming connector on the adapter board that comes with the Atmel-ICE and that it's oriented correctly on the Nano's header.

If that all fails then something is broken.

Comment: I had used a properly connector, of coarse, and i had find the both AVR & SAM ports.
Have you idea anymore?